# Java method never called while using JSON RPC in Struts2

Tags: java, javascript, json, struts2, json-rpc

I'm trying to get some code working that a previous developer has written.
Yep, he now left the company. :-(

I have a JSON RPC call being made from the JS code.
The JS all runs fine and the callback method gets an object back (not an error object).

But the method on the Java class never gets hit.
The smd method does get hit though.

---

```
public String smd()
{
   return SUCCESS; // break point reaches here
}

@SMDMethod
public void updateRowValueForField(String key, String value, String fieldname)
{
   // We never get into this method.
}
```

---

```
<package name="EntryBarRPC" namespace="/" extends="star-default">

    <action name="ebToggleSelection" class="eboggleSelectionAction" method="smd">
        <interceptor-ref name="jsonStack">
            <param name="enableSMD">true</param>
        </interceptor-ref>
        <result type="json">
            <param name="enableSMD">true</param>
        </result>
    </action>
</package>
```

---

I'm stumped as to why, or what I'm missing.
I've read [JSON plugin page](http://cwiki.apache.org/S2PLUGINS/json-plugin.html) over and over.

I think I just need another set of eyes.

Note: no errors in the Tomcat console, no JS errors.

Anyone got any clues?
Cheers 
Jeff Porter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to include the javascript code. From the example:

```
<s:url id="smdUrl" namespace="/nodecorate" action="SMDAction" />
<script type="text/javascript">
    //load dojo RPC
    dojo.require("dojo.rpc.*");

    //create service object(proxy) using SMD (generated by the json result)
    var service = new dojo.rpc.JsonService("${smdUrl}");

    //function called when remote method returns
    var callback = function(bean) {
        alert("Price for " + bean.type + " is " + bean.price);
    };

    //parameter
    var bean = {type: "Mocca"};

    //execute remote method
    var defered = service.doSomething(bean, 5);

    //attach callback to defered object
    defered.addCallback(callback);
</script>
```

Are you sure you call service.updateRowValueForField(key, value, fieldname) and not something different?

Further, your method returns a void (e.g. doesn't return anything). What did you expect to get?

Answer (score 2):

New version fixes my problems.

[Google JSON plugin](http://code.google.com/p/jsonplugin/)

Comment: I know its old post...but i am not able to get this work either...i am on 2.2.3 and in javascript when i say service.doSomething...it says doSomething not defined...sounds logical as there is no method saying doSomething in Json service. That example is not correct..something is missing there...

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that you need to update the `smd()` method to actually call `updateRowValueForField()` rather than simply return immediately. Looks like the previous developer never actually hooked up the methods.